# Vue 3 composition api - ref doesn't update when it's using another ref in it

Tags: vuejs3

below is the basic idea of what I want to achieve. I realize that I didn't include my entire code but this is what I'm stuck with.

when I change the first const (to say, 'hockey') `const thevaluethatchanges = ref('baseball')` value consoles out as 'hockey' but in the second const it stays as 'baseball'.

how can I get the value to update in the second const?

```
const thevaluethatchanges = ref('baseball')
const axiosdata = ref(`sampleurlq=${thevaluethatchanges.value}&samplestuff=20etc`)
```

thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for `computed`.

Syntax in your example would be like this

```
const axiosData = computed(() => `sampleurlq=${thevaluethatchanges.value}&samplestuff=20etc`)
```

Documentation can be found here: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#computed

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - Not all my variables were reactive.

I figured out my problem, so for anyone who may stumble here in the future with similar issues:

I had a input field and a button, once you hit the button, I wanted the data i'm calling to change based on what was in the input (from baseball to hockey say).

I had two divs for testing one with the data, one with the variable that gets changed, the data wasn't updating but the variable was.

what i ended up doing was making a reactive object with all the url bits, a watch method to track changes in that reactive object, which then called a function that 'assembled' the url and allowed the template to update.

simplified code

```
const all-avail-data = ref('')

const allData = reactive({
  thevaluethatchanges: 'baseball',
  thebaseurl: 'https://whateverurl',
  therestoftheurl: '&otherparameters',
})

watch(allData, (currentValue, oldValue) => {
  console.log(`allData.thevaluethatchanges has changed to: ${allData.thevaluethatchanges}`)
  function-that-assembles-url()
})

const function-that-assembles-url = () => {
  const assembleurl = allData.thebaseurl + allData.thevaluethatchanges + allData.therestoftheurl
  //code to use axios to make http request
  all-avail-data = whatever-comes-from-axios-code-above
}
```